# Inline "if": obtain and test a value in one call

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have the following

```
IPublishedContentProperty propTitle; // the type is not nullable

// Compiles, 2 GetProperty calls
var title = x.GetProperty("title").HasValue ? x.GetProperty("title").Value : null;

// Does not compile, 1 GetProperty call
    title = (propTitle=x.GetProperty("title") && propTitle.HasValue) ?propTitle.Value:null;
```

Suppose the `GetProperty` is a time consuming operation, and I would like to call this method only once.
So, the first line is as it compiles. The second one it does not, but is what I would like to achieve.

Constraints:

1. .NET specific version;
2. do not use the `if` blocks.

PS. `.HasValue` does not mean the type is nullable, is just a type having such a bool property.

[image]

Comment: You do realize that your code is equivalent to `var title = x.GetProperty("title")`?

Comment: You can write extension method that will internally save x.GetProperty into variable and then use condition ?

Comment: no extension methods @Heinzi, is not true, you forget the .Value

Comment: @Serge: Sorry, my fault, it looked like `x.GetProperty` returned a nullable value type, but it's apparently something different.

Comment: @Heinzi: good point, is not a nullable type returned.

Comment: Have you tried putting `propTitle = x.GetProperty("title")` in extra parenthesis? It could be that `&&` has higher precedence than `=`. (Sorry, can't test it right now.)

Comment: @Heinzi is right your code means if value for title is `null` return `null`. Maybe what you meant is that if there is no property 'Title' return `null`

Comment: If so you can use `?` operator like: `var title = x.GetProperty("title")?.Value;`

Comment: @roozbehS: `?` operator is from the C# 6th version. but good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause for not compiling: `&&` is evaluated before the `=`. And `&&` is obviously not a valid operation on those types.

This can be fixed with a pair of braces. The `.HasValue` can then be applied to the result of the assignment (which is *the object or value that was assigned*).

```
title = (propTitle = x.GetProperty("title")).HasValue ? propTitle.Value : null;
```

**Edit:** you can make this expression shorter and more readable by defining an Extension Method. If you are using the construct in more than one place then it will also reduce redundancy and clutter.

Example:

```
namespace Your.Project.Helpers
{
    public static class PropertyHelper
    {
                                               // use actual type (or interface)
        public static string GetValueOrDefault(this Property p) 
        {
            return p.HasValue ? p.Value : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using Your.Project.Helpers;

...

var title = x.GetProperty("title").GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: yeah ! great advice, and was so simple!

Comment: what is a pity, that the `propTitle` should be declared before that code as a separate variable... there is any way to inline declare the variable?

Comment: See my... extension

Comment: good idea, but my case is too specific and not used in other places to really made an extension method. however in general is a good idea. My problem is also I am in the cshtml page that does not need recompilation, but an extension method will need one, so there's dlls to replace... more complex for such a bagatelle )